# Having trouble testing check box on change within CardHeader Avatar={}

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, material-ui, enzyme

I've implemented something similar to the example provided by [MaterialUI on their TrasferList](https://material-ui.com/components/transfer-list/). I'm having trouble accessing a checkbox within avatar={}. The project is using Jest/Enzyme for testing. For simplicity, the below example is straight from their docs with the added id. I've added ids to things I want to test to make it easier to use the .find function.

```
export interface IListItem {
   itemId: number;
   itemName: string;
   isChecked: boolean;
}

interface IProps {
   listName: string;
   list: IListItem[];
   setList: any;
}

function checkAllItems(function checkAllItems(check: boolean, list: IListItem[], setList: any) {
   let tempList = [...list];
   for (var item of tempList) {
      item.isChecked = check;
   }
   setList(tempList);
}

export function ToggleableListComponent({ listName, list, setList }: IProps) {
  return (
    <CardHeader
       id="check-all-card"
       avatar={
         <Checkbox
           id="check-all"
           checked={areAllItemsChecked(list)}
           onChange={(e) => checkAllItems(e.target.checked, list, setList)}
         />
       }
       title={listName}
       subheader={`${numberOfChecked(list)}/${list.length} selected`}
  />)}
```

I'm trying to access the checkmark with the .find enzyme function to ultimately simulate a change.

```
it("Tests checking all items in list", () => {
   let defaultProps = {
      listName: "test",
      list: [] as IListItem[],
      setList: jest.fn(),
   }
    const mockedEvent = { target: {checked: true}};
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <ToggleableListComponent {...defaultProps} />
    );
    wrapper.find("#check-all").simulate("change", mockedEvent); 
}
```

The above line returns an error "Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead."
How would I access that checkbox to simulate the change event?

Let me know if I need to provide more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got curious and I had a chance to reproduce it myself, so here is the problem.

First of all, you have to use `mount` instead of `shallow` in order for all your child components (including avatar checkbox) to render. Using `shallow` is the reason you get

```
Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.
```

This message means that `wrapper.find` have not found a given selector, which means that your checkbox did not render.

However, when you just change `shallow` to `mount` you get the following error

```
Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 5 found instead.
```

And that means that there are 5 elements with `id="check-all"` which at first glance makes no sense.

However, when you checkout the markup of the rendered component using `console.log(wrapper.debug())` you can see that Material-UI actually creates a whole bunch of wrappers over your checkbox with the SAME ATTRIBUTES (including `id`). Therefore, you end up with 5 elements with the same id.

To fix this issue you have to specify the selector by checking out the rendered tree from console. The following selector works just fine: `".MuiIconButton-label > #check-all"`

So your test should look like this:

```
it("Tests checking all items in list", () => {
   let defaultProps = {
      listName: "test",
      list: [] as IListItem[],
      setList: jest.fn(),
   }
    const mockedEvent = { target: {checked: true}};
    
    // using mount instead of shallow
    const wrapper = mount(
      <ToggleableListComponent {...defaultProps} />
    );

    // using new selector .MuiIconButton-label > #check-all
    wrapper.find(".MuiIconButton-label > #check-all").simulate("change", mockedEvent); 
    ...
}
```

Comment: Really interesting. I tried doing mount as well. But I did run into the 1 of 5 nodes. I was using wrapper.find("#check-all").at(0-5).simulate("change", mockedEvent) and never had luck no matter the which node I tried. Really appreciate the input! I even was running it via Jest plugin in VSCode to step through and could see a node that had the event I wanted to trigger but never could get it.